# Java ME image exception

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I have a interesting bug. When I create an `com.sun.lwuit.Image` in Java ME, I receive an exception:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current display!
        at com.sun.lwuit.Display.getImplementation: com.sun.lwuit.impl.LWUITImplementation getImplementation() (Display.java:437)
        at com.sun.lwuit.Image.createImage: com.sun.lwuit.Image createImage(byte[],int,int) (Image.java:558)`

As I suggest, according to the text exception, the image tries to bring himself on screen, but in code, I just simply don't reach to visualization.

In what may be the problem?

Comment: What version of LWUIT you are using? Also just post your code.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution yourself. Bug occurred because of that I did not initialize graphics, like this:

    Container container = arg0.getContainer();
    container.setVisible(true);
    Display.init(container);
    Display.getInstance().setPureTouch(true);


Perhaps my post will be useful to others:)

Comment: is there a way to close this type of questions.. if the asking person is not bothering ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Bug occurred because I did not initialize graphics, like this:

```
Container container = arg0.getContainer();
container.setVisible(true);
Display.init(container);
Display.getInstance().setPureTouch(true);
```